# boto s3 get_contents_to_filename IncompleteRead errors downloading large file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to download large files from s3 using boto. Can anyone say whether they've been able to do this successfully?

I have the following method Im trying to use to download a 35GB file I was able to upload to my s3 bucket.

```
def download_file(bucketname, filename, destination):
    bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucketname)
    key = bucket.get_key(filename)
    amount_of_retries = 5
    destination = os.path.abspath(destination)
    def _download(retries = amount_of_retries):
        try:
            logging.info("downloading %s to %s:" % (filename, os.path.abspath(destination)))
            key.get_contents_to_filename(destination + "/" + key.name.encode('utf8').split("/")[-1], num_cb=15)
            logging.info("downloaded %s to %s" % (filename, destination))
        except Exception as e:
            if retries:
                logging.error("could not download %s to %s: \n%s\n Will try %d more times" % (filename, destination, e, retries))
                _download(retries = retries -1)
            else:
                logging.error("Done retrying.")
    _download()
```

The download starts alright, it gets at least 2.5GB of the file that I've seen, but at some point when I come back to it, I see that it's failed. I get the following:

```
2014-07-03 19:07:41,023:ERROR:could not download database/staging/database-2014-7-1.sql.gz to /mnt/database_backups:
IncompleteRead(0 bytes read, 31472225275 more expected)
Will try 5 more times
....................
Will try 1 more times
2014-07-03 19:07:41,034:INFO:downloading database/staging/database-2014-7-1.sql.gz to /mnt/database_backups:
2014-07-03 19:07:41,036:ERROR:Done retrying.
```

The retries don't even start, so it's like I'm being shut down from the other side. Is there a reliable way to download large files from s3?

Comment: I'm also looking for this because, apparently, s3cmd failed to handle this. s3cmd would hang there unpredictably for huge file, like 10GB or more.

Comment: Did you ever resolve the issue?